# Library for using @Url.Content in .cshtml file (Razor Views)

Tags: css, url, razor, using, asp.net-webpages

The problem i am facing is in the screenshot below:

[image]

I don't know the library? What should I write on top with @using ???

Comment: Razor version? MVC or webpages?

Comment: how do I check for Razor version??
And its webpages

Comment: so, is there anything we can do ???